# AJax/PHP Login Form - Mysql Database [Jquery Mobile]

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue with AJAX/PHP form submission.

My ajax is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
           checkLogin();
        });

        function checkLogin()
        {
             $.ajax({
                url: "login.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    username: $("#username").val(),
                    password: $("#password").val()
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'true')
                    {
                        window.location.replace("main.html");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#errorMessage").html(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
```

My form:

```
<form id="loginForm" data-ajax="false">
    <label id="errorMessage"></label>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    </div><!-- End Contained Fields -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div><!-- End Contained Fields -->
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" />
    </div><!-- End Contained Fields -->
    </form><!-- End Form -->
```

And then my login.php script:

```
    <?php

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mobile;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');
    try {
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
        if(intval($stmt->fetchColumn()) === 1)
        {
            echo 'true';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'false';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "An error has occured!";
    }
}

?>
```

I originally had programmed my whole JQuery Mobile application using just raw php, but recently found out that I must use AJAX and Html to be able to port it to IOS and Android using PhoneGap.

I'm rather new to using ajax and have read as many articles that I could/topics here to try to get it to work. Unsure if I'm having a syntax issue or just not handling it correctly.

My local machine is loading a mysql server (database name is mobile, table I'm trying to load is users). I know that part is all correct because it works fine with php.

Could someone explain my issue? Thank you.

Comment: Add `data-ajax=false` to submit button. And use `.on('submit', function ()` if you're using jquery 1.7 and higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this:

```
$("$errorMessage").html("Attempting to login...");
```

should be:

```
$("#errorMessage").html("Attempting to login...");
```

or, if you have previously defined a $errorMessage variable like this:

```
var $errorMessage = $("#errorMessage");
```

it should be :

```
$errorMessage.html("Attempting to login...");
```

EDIT:

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) : "For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement....."

you can try:

```
....
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'");
if (intval($stmt->fetchColumn()) === 1) {   //make sure it's not a string 
  echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   // OR perform another SELECT query to retrieve the data 
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
.....
```

Comment: Shoot that was an issue, still bouncing back though without displaying an error message or redirecting the page.

Comment: I tried that. I think this is an issue dealing with JQuery Mobile. The form is not even reaching the php script (at least it seems like that). I tried using a query string and the php script works fine. It's my unfamiliarity with ajax that is causing the problem I believe. (I updated my main topic to show what I have now)

Comment: .. by now it's better you deal with jQuery .post() - look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) .. are you using some application debugger?

Comment: I see that ad blocker was not displaying error messages. So I'll re-tackle this again with errors finally displaying.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
 window.location.replace('main.html');
```

Change it to:

```
 window.location.href='main.html';
```

Comment: That shouldn't really affect much. The replace function is used to load a new document into the current one. I replaced it to see if it would work and still is redirecting back to the index.html page without displaying an error message or going to the main.html. Thanks though!